# How to reference sibling list items

Tags: html, css

I building a common css user file for two different web pages. I have  unordered lists on two different pages.  In the actual html there are lots of unordered lists deeply nested in divs and what have your.  The actual number of list items is greater than shown here. I need to format the first set of list items differently than the second set. There is nothing different in the ul coding.  There is too much css to wade through for other differences.

```
<-- list in first page -->
<ul class="our-list">
<li class="group item" data-filter-id="draft">a little bit of <span>text</span></li>
<li class="group item" data-filter-id="contentstatus[published]">other <span>text</span></li>
<li class="group item" data-filter-id="participated">last of the <span>text</span></li>
</ul>

<-- list in second page -->
<ul class="our-list">
<li class="group item" data-filter-id="One">a little <span>text</span></li>
<li class="group item" data-filter-id="Two">the <span>text</span></li>
<li class="group item" data-filter-id="Three">last  <span>text</span></li>
</ul>
```

The only discernible difference that I have noticed is different data-filter-id fields.  I need to reference the span tags in the first list and not the second.

I've written this css to address the first li in the first list:

```
li[data-filter-id="draft"] span { 
         background-color: yellow !important;
        }
```

Is there some way to refer to the sibling li tags in this css? 
I could code:

```
li[data-filter-id="draft"] span,
li[data-filter-id="contentstatus\[published\]"] span,
li[data-filter-id="participated"] span, { 
         background-color: yellow !important;
        }
```

But is there some shortcut I could code to have to list all the adjacent list items?

This this the correct way to escape the imbedded [] in css?

```
li[data-filter-id="contentstatus\[published\]"] span,
```

Is this the correct way to include the class on the css for the li tag?

```
li.group.item[data-filter-id="draft"] span,
```

Comment: Are the parent and ancestor elements the same for the `ul` on both pages? All you need is one unique `id` as an ancestor in the first page (in other words, the `id` is unique across pages) then you can make the `ul` a descendant of that `id`, and it applies only to that page.

Comment: I looked at the preceding eight levels and the css tags are all the same.  There is around 65k lines of html.  first page is: <my list of content, which you need an appleid to see> second page is https://discussions.apple.com/community/mac_os/mac_os_x_technologies/content  I'm reformatting the sidebar

Comment: I gotta run now, but if possible, find a single element that is unique to that page and higher up in the DOM. Make your `ul` a descendant and that should work. I'll check back later. Good luck.

Comment: I there some way to compare the two pages.  Firefox inspector displays the precedence order, but number of levels shown is small.  I can only see about 25% of the precedence order. Is there some way of extracting this info to a file?  Would be nice to automate this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ul:first-of-type > li` as a selector for all `li` items inside the first `ul`

If that isn't sufficient (you write about different pages), use a class on the according `ul` and address the child `li`s of that class like `ul.my-class > li`

Comment: but I know nothing unique about the ul.  The class info is the same on the ul.

Comment: So you can't change the HTML (i.e. add a class)? In this case, maybe the `body`tag has a unique ID or class (Wordpress for example does that automatically). Then you could use  selector like `.page1 ul:first-of-type > li`